# WooCommerce send email notification to admin for specific order status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

Here below is my code for sending notification email to admin when order status becomes "processing":

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'process_new_order_notification', 20, 1 );

function process_new_order_notification( $order_id ) {

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    //Order status processing
    if( ! $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) return;

    // Send "New Email" notification (to admin)
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

But it doesn't work as the admin don't receive any email when order status becomes processing. I think there something wrong with my code. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `woocommerce_order_status_$STATUS_TRANSITION[to]` composite hook for "processing"status transition changing `$STATUS_TRANSITION[to]` to `processing`, which will simplify and compact the code, like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'process_new_order_notification', 20, 2 );
function process_new_order_notification( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Send "New Email" notification (to admin)
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.

> **Since WooCommerce 5+:** [Allow re-sending New Order Notification in WooCommerce 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604256/allow-re-sending-new-order-notification-in-woocommerce-5/66604522#66604522)